# How to access a dictionary key value present inside a list?

Tags: python

Suppose I have the following list:

```
list = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'c': 3, 'd': 4}, {'e': 5, 'f': 6}]
```

How do I access a particular value of key say `d`?

Comment: What's wrong with `list[1]['d']`?

Comment: how about accessing two keys, is that possible? list[0]['a','b'] @MattBall

Answer (score 54):

Index the list then the dict.

```
print L[1]['d']
```

Answer (score 21):

First of all don't use 'list' as variable name.

If you have simple dictionaries with unique keys then you can do the following(note that new dictionary object with all items from sub-dictionaries will be created):

```
res  = {}
for line in listOfDicts:
   res.update(line)
res['d']
>>> 4
```

Otherwise:

```
getValues = lambda key,inputData: [subVal[key] for subVal in inputData if key in subVal]
getValues('d', listOfDicts)
>>> [4]
```

Or very base:

```
def get_value(listOfDicts, key):
    for subVal in listOfDicts:
        if key in subVal:
            return subVal[key]
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you are using the anti-pattern `funcname = lambda ...`.

Answer (score 17):

You haven't provided enough context to provide an accurate answer (i.e. how do you want to handle identical keys in multiple dicts?)

One answer is to iterate the list, and attempt to get 'd'

```
mylist = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'c': 3, 'd': 4}, {'e': 5, 'f': 6}]
myvalues = [i['d'] for i in mylist if 'd' in i]
```

Another answer is to access the dict directly (by list index), though you have to know that the key is present

```
mylist[1]['d']
```

Comment: @raja: No need to thank me, and especially no need to call me Sir! :) Remember to upvote the answers you think are helpful.

Answer (score 5):

If you know which `dict` in the list has the key you're looking for, then you already have the solution (as presented by Matt and Ignacio). However, if you don't know which dict has this key, then you could do this:

```
def getValueOf(k, L):
    for d in L:
        if k in d:
            return d[k]
```

Comment: Fix 'if k in in d:' to 'if k in d:'

Comment: this doesn't work if I'm looking for the value of a particular key in a nested dictionary that's in a list

Answer (score 4):

To get all the values from a list of dictionaries, use the following code :

```
list = [{'text': 1, 'b': 2}, {'text': 3, 'd': 4}, {'text': 5, 'f': 6}]
subtitle=[]
for value in list:
   subtitle.append(value['text'])
```