# Why are my indexed outputs printing vertically in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a Python script where I am digging into several JSON dictionaries associated with one list, I have referenced this thread to access the dictionaries.

Each one of my outputs comes from the 0th dictionary of a list; 
Here is an example of the structure which illustrates why I am indexing these values; So in my script I would like to use 0th index to access the items of the 1st dictionary, 1st index of the 2nd, and so on.  In this case, container numbers, but when doing so my output prints vertically.

```
{
    "ListOfLa311Containers": {
        "La311Containers": [
            {
                "ActiveStatus": "Y",
                "CollectionLocation": "Curb",
                "ContactFirstName": "BOSSupervisor",
                "ContactLastName": "CallCenter",
                "ContainerNumber": "6356543654445",
                "ContainerSize": "30Gallon(Small)Black",
                "ContainerType": "BlackRefuse",
                "DamageonAxle": "",
                "DamageonBody": "",
                "DamageonHandleEndcap": "",
                "DamageonLid": "",
                "DamageonWheels": "",
                "DeliveryReason": "Exchange",
                "DriverFirstName": "",
                "DriverLastName": "",
                "ExchangeDetails": "",
                "GatedCommunityMultifamilyDwelling": "",
                "LastUpdatedBy": "SANCID132",
                "MobileHomeSpace": "",
                "Name": "062420151714334791",
                "PickupReason": "",
                "PurposeofSR": "",
                "RequestFor": "Delivery",
                "ServiceDateRendered": "",
                "TruckNo": "",
                "Type": "Containers"
            },
            {
                "ActiveStatus": "Y",
                "CollectionLocation": "Curb",
                "ContactFirstName": "BOSSupervisor",
                "ContactLastName": "CallCenter",
                "ContainerNumber": "3543545445234324653",
                "ContainerSize": "60Gallon(Small)Black",
                "ContainerType": "BlackRefuse",
                "DamageonAxle": "",
                "DamageonBody": "",
                "DamageonHandleEndcap": "",
                "DamageonLid": "",
                "DamageonWheels": "",
                "DeliveryReason": "Exchange",
                "DriverFirstName": "",
                "DriverLastName": "",
                "ExchangeDetails": "",
                "GatedCommunityMultifamilyDwelling": "",
                "LastUpdatedBy": "SANCID132",
                "MobileHomeSpace": "",
                "Name": "062420151714334791",
                "PickupReason": "",
                "PurposeofSR": "",
                "RequestFor": "Delivery",
                "ServiceDateRendered": "",
                "TruckNo": "",
                "Type": "Containers"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

[How to access a dictionary key value present inside a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521892/how-to-access-a-dictionary-key-value-present-inside-a-list)

Script:

```
  try:
        k_container = ' '
        k_container_size = ' '
        container_info = " "
        for sr in Containers:
          if("La311Containers" in Containers):
            lcontainers311 = Containers ["La311Containers"]
            for Containers in lcontainers311:
                k_container_size_1= Containers['ContainerSize']
                k_container_type_1 = Containers['ContainerType']
                k_damage_lid_1 = Containers['DamageonLid']
                k_damage_axle_1 = Containers['DamageonAxle']
                k_damage_on_body_1 = Containers['DamageonBody']
                k_damage_on_handle_1 = Containers['DamageonHandleEndcap']
                k_damage_on_wheels_1 = Containers ['DamageonWheels']
                k_container_number_1= Containers['ContainerNumber']
                # print k_container_number_1
        for container_number in k_container_number_1:
            print container_number[0]
```

Output:

```
r
6
b
7
6
5
8
9
8
7
6

n
/
a




o
9
r
1
6
5
2
5
5
5


R
9
R
0
1
1
5
4
2
0
4
5

R
6
B
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
4

n
/
a

r
6
m
0
7
1
7
1
5
6
4
1

R
3
G
1
2
3
4
5
1
2
3
4
5

R
6
B
0
1
0
3
7
8
9
4
5
6


R
6
B
0
1
0
3
5
2
4
6
9
8

R
9
B
1
2
3
7
6
4
4
3
6

r
6
g
0
1
0
2
0
3
0
6
9
1

r
3
b
o
1
0
2
3
6
9
7


r
6
m
6
8
9
4
4
3
8
5

N
/
A

N
/
a


r
6
b
1
2
3
4
6
9
6

r
6
b
1
2
3
4
5
6
7

R
9
R
0
1
0
2
0
3
5
6
7
8

R
9
R
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

r
9
b
0
8
0
1
5
4
6
4






n
/
a

r
6
b
7
0
5
0
0
5
6
5
6

n
/
a

r
6
b
1
2
4
1
2
4
1
4
6
7

r
9
g
0
3
0
0
0
0
0
2
2
2

R
6
B
0
1
0
3
0
5
2
6
3
9

R
9
B
1
2
3
5
3
1
6
5

r
6
b
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8


N
/
A

R
9
B
1
2
0
1
2
3
6
7
7


R
6
R
0
1
0
7
1
1
1
1
1
1

R
6
B
0
7
0
7
1
5
2
5
2
9

R
6
B
0
7
0
7
1
5
2
5
8
6

R
9
R
0
7
0
4
0
0
0
0
3
4


n
/
a



n
/
a

n
/
a

n
/
a

1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1




n
/
a

n
/
a






r
2
A
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1

r
3
a
3
5
3
4
5
3
5
3
4
5

r
3
v
3
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2


8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8



R
3
B
1
2
3
4
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: Why are you using the same variable name `containers` for both loops?

Comment: Unless specified otherwise, `print` will always append a `newline`

Comment: Containers is used in both loops because it references a key in a top-level json object `Containers[LaListOf311Containers]` the data that I am referencing is accessed by that key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the print command automatically adds a new line character.
A nice hack would be to use:

```
answer=""
for container_number in k_container_number_1:
        answer+=str(container_number[0])
print answer
```

Another way to do this is to use standard output:

```
import sys
for container_number in k_container_number_1:
        sys.stdout.write(container_number[0])
```

**EDIT:**
If I understand the issue correctly, you need to check if the container is the first or not. Therefore I replaced your "for" loop with "if" statement. Here is the code:

```
    
try:
    k_container = ' '
    k_container_size = ' '
    container_info = " "
    for sr in Containers:
        if("La311Containers" in Containers):
            lcontainers311 = Containers ["La311Containers"]
            for Containers in lcontainers311:
                k_container_size_1= Containers['ContainerSize']
                k_container_type_1 = Containers['ContainerType']
                k_damage_lid_1 = Containers['DamageonLid']
                k_damage_axle_1 = Containers['DamageonAxle']
                k_damage_on_body_1 = Containers['DamageonBody']
                k_damage_on_handle_1 = Containers['DamageonHandleEndcap']
                k_damage_on_wheels_1 = Containers ['DamageonWheels']
                k_container_number_1= Containers['ContainerNumber']
                # print k_container_number_1
                if Containers==lcontainers311[0]:
                    print k_container_number_1
```

Comment: your suggetion works, however all values are still printing, not just the 0 index.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I am not sure of what you want. Do you want to print the 1st character of the container numbers of all the containers in the list?

Comment: No I want to print out the first container number of the 1st dictionary in each list.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your issue:

```
for container_number in k_container_number_1:
    print container_number[0]
```

You are iterating over `k_container_number_1`, which is a string containing the container number. Iteration over a string yields the individual characters in the string. Thus `container_number` is *each character* of the container number. Python is printing each character on its own line, *exactly as you have told it to.*

Solution: if you don't want each character printed on its own line, don't print each character on its own line. Replace the unnecessary loop with:

```
print k_container_number_1
```

Also, this should be indented an additional level so that it inside the `for Containers in lcontainers311` loop, thereby printing the container number for each container. Given your output it appears that it's already printing all the container numbers, implying that the code you are actually running is not the code you posted here.

Comment: The thing is, is that I don't want to grab all container numbers at once, since there are multiple dictionaries within my list I would like to grab container number dict1, containernumber dict2, etc.

Comment: OK... well, what do you mean by "grab"? Store them in a list, so you can then print it later?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I will write them to an array later with NumPy.

Comment: Well, then you need to create a list and put stuff in there... not sure why you are printing them to begin with! Give that a shot and if you have trouble with it, post a new question asking about that rather than about your print issue.