# Python:Accessing a particular dictionary present in a list of dictionary

Tags: python

```
list1:[
    {"name": "Tom", "age": 10},
    {"name": "Mark", "age": 5},
    {"name": "Pam", "age": 7}
       ]
```

I want to access the second dictionary. I have tried with giving key.

```
next(item for item in dicts if item["name"] == "Mark")
```

But i dont have the key. I want to do some operation with the help of second dictionary. Can any one help?'
Here i want to access each dictionary without indices & doing some operation with each dictionary & moving towards next dictionary to do operation for next dictionary & so on. Is there any way?

Comment: Any suggestion using for loop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access a dictionary key value present inside a list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521892/how-to-access-a-dictionary-key-value-present-inside-a-list)

Comment: I've downvoted your question because I don't think it provides much value to future visitors and shows little research effort. Accessing items in lists and dictionaries is well documented in countless Python tutorials, and there are already multiple SO questions providing examples of variations.

Comment: Do not edit question and thus make answers invalid?

Answer (score 2):

Since `list1` is a `list` of `dictionary` so try to access dictionaries using list indices ( for this case 0-2)-

```
 >>>print list1[1]["name"]
>>>Mark
>>>lsit1[1]["name"] = 'Blah'
>>>lsit1
>>>[{'age': 10, 'name': 'Tom'}, {'age': 5, 'name': 'Blah'}, {'age': 7, 'name': 'Pam'}]
>>>del lsit1[1]['name'] #Delete a key
>>>lsit1
>>>[{'age': 10, 'name': 'Tom'}, {'age': 5}, {'age': 7, 'name': 'Pam'}]
>>>lsit1[1]['new_name']='Test'  #Add a key
>>>lsit1
>>>[{'age': 10, 'name': 'Tom'}, {'new_name': 'Test', 'age': 5}, {'age': 7, 'name': 'Pam'}]
```

---

EDIT-

It looks your data is `json` compatiable then try json module-

```
>>>import json
>>>#use json.loads and dumps to format data as below
>>>data =  {'list1':[{"name":"Tom","age":10},{"name":"Mark","age":5},{"name":"Pam","age":7}]}
>>>data['list1'][1]
>>>{'age': 5, 'name': 'Mark'}
```

Comment: I need the whole dictionary like   :  {"name": "Mark", "age": 5}

Comment: I can't use direct indices. i ll be hard coded. Any other tricks?

Comment: Add more sample data i think it is a part of json data?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `indexing`.

```
In [134]: list1[1]['name']
Out[134]: 'Mark'
```

For second `dict`.

```
In [137]: l[1]
Out[137]: {'age': 5, 'name': 'Mark'}
```

for solve through `for` loop and for accessing the second item in `list`.

```
In [139]: for k, v in enumerate(l):
    if k==1:
        print v
   .....:         
{'age': 5, 'name': 'Mark'}
```

Comment: Any suggestion using for loop?

Comment: why you need `for` loop when you have way better approach.

Comment: i need for loop because i don't know the keys & all

Comment: According to my question your answer is correct. But i need a small help is like if i want to iterate all the dictionaries in list & want to do some operation for each dictionary then how can i do? Is there any way?

Comment: That i can understand, but my doubt is how to access the Nth dictionary in list & that shouldn't be hard coded like using integer indices.
While accesing each dictionary i am doing some operation with that & moving towards next dictionary. If u dont understand then i ll explain a little bit more.

Comment: if you are not using `indexing` then you have to traverse all the list element one by one . Or at easy way if you want to access the last `dictionary` then reverse the `list` using `list1.reverse()` and access first `dict`.

Comment: I hope this helped you out,

Comment: @HariKrishna Again it can be done by `for` loop, or if you don't want iteration through `for` loop, try:- `list_iter = iter(list1)` `dict1 =  next(list_iter)` `dict2 =  next(list_iter)` `dict13 =  next(list_iter)`. Operate `dict1, dict2, dict3` as you want.

Comment: If there are 100 number of dictionary present in a list then i need to assign each with a new dict? or do u have any better way?

Comment: Then `for` loop is the best thing as per my knowledge. I think there are other answers at SO that can help you out for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
list1[1]["name"]="some thing"
```