# Django Rest Framework get key from serializer.data

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Ok so my question is very simple, after calling def create(): It returns me multiple dictionaries, so I want to get a key from this dict.

here is my view:

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    #data = json.dumps(request.data)
    user = self.request.user
    if user.groups.filter(name='advertisers').exists():
        serializer = CampaignSerializer(data=request.data)
        adsImageSerializer = AdsImagesSerializer()
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save(advertiser=self.request.user)
            raise Exception(serializer.validated_data['id'])
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    else:
        return Response({
                            'status':'Unauthorized',
                            'message':'This account is not authorized to do this request'
                    }, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
    return super(CampaignStart, self).perform_create(serializer)
```

as you can see I am trying to acces this by a break point in

> raise Exception(serializer.validated_data['id'])

When i print the:

> raise Exception(serializer.data)

it returns me this:

> {'advertiser': OrderedDict([('username', u'demo'), ('first_name', u'genti'), ('last_name', u'elmazi'), ('email', u'demo@demo.com'), ('password', u'pbkdf2_sha256$24000$VuPC2uIB4Lb1$Rc9++gdVbAtnNgsD9XxzUx8vlVIaIxztfjNKRY0FOwM='), ('advertiser', OrderedDict([('phone', u'+38971666022'), ('address', u'balindollska bb'), ('state', u'macedonia'), ('city', u'gostivar'), ('ZIP', u'1230'), ('country', u'MK'), ('company', u'maxleads'), ('web_name', u'maxleads'), ('web_url', u'http://www.test.com'), ('web_desc', u'demo description'), ('web_category', u'Automotive'), ('online_revenue', 546546), ('meth_of_conv', u'pay-per-sale')]))]), 'name': u'Demo Campaign', 'end_date': '2016-06-23', 'pay_off': 30, 'description': u'demo description', 'CPC': 2, 'locations': u'Macedonia', 'budget': 10, 'commission': 10, 'keywords': u'keyword 1, keyword 2', 'ads': [OrderedDict([('id', 26), ('headline', u'Demo Headline'), ('description_1', u''), ('description_2', u''), ('display_url', u''), ('final_url', u''), ('mobile_url', u''), ('advertiser', 1)])], 'adsImages': [], 'type': u'PayPerSale', 'start_date': '2016-06-23', 'land_page': u'http://www.test.com', 'CPM': 1}

I want to access this:

> ads': [OrderedDict([('id', 26),

how can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "id" key is in the "abs" dict, so you need access "abs" first. Then access "id" key.

Try this:

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    #data = json.dumps(request.data)
    user = self.request.user
    if user.groups.filter(name='advertisers').exists():
        serializer = CampaignSerializer(data=request.data)
        adsImageSerializer = AdsImagesSerializer()
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save(advertiser=self.request.user)
            raise Exception(serializer.validated_data['abs']['id'])
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    else:
        return Response({
                            'status':'Unauthorized',
                            'message':'This account is not authorized to do this request'
                    }, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
    return super(CampaignStart, self).perform_create(serializer)
```

Comment: why it says to me : TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: This is because your dic is in a list. You have to access de index of the list before access de dict.

Comment: Take a look  in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521892/how-to-access-a-dictionary-key-value-present-inside-a-list

Comment: If your list will have always one item ("advertiser") you can access like this: serializer.validated_data[0]['abs']['id']

Comment: it gives me a KeyErros, maybe because this is an OrderedDict

Comment: Try this: serializer.validated_data['abs'][0]['id'], The abs is a list of ditcs, so in the 'abs' list you have to access the index of the dict. Then access the key 'id'.