# Accessings deeply nested dictionary/list elements/values in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

I've been racking my brain on this problem and the logic needed to step through this output from Google Maps API.

Essentially I'm using google maps Distance_Matrix:
Here is an example of the returned information from a call of the API for distance/time between two addresses, which I've assigned to variable *distanceMatrixReturn* for this example.

```
  distanceMatrixReturn = {
            {'destination_addresses': ['This would be ADDRESS 1'],
            'status': 'OK',
            'rows': [
            {
                'elements': [
                 {
                     'duration_in_traffic': {
                           'text': '10 mins', 'value': 619},
                            'status': 'OK',
                             'distance': {'text': '2.8 mi', 'value': 4563},
                             'duration': {'text': '9 mins', 'value': 540}}]}], 
                            }]
              }], 
    'origin_addresses': ['This would be ADDRESS 2'] 
}
```

Now, being a python newbie struggling with nested dictionaries and lists; 
Here is my thought process:

I want to access the value `'2.8 mi'` that to my impression, is within a dictionary tied to the key 'text', which is in turn inside a dictionary assigned to the key `'distance'`, which is in another dictionary with the key `'duration_in_traffic'`.

The key `'duration_in_traffic'` seems to be within a list, tied to the dictionary key `'elements'`, which in turn is in a list tied to another dictionary key, `'rows'`.

Now, this seems very very convoluted and there must be an easy way to handle this situation, or maybe my logic is just off about the nested within nested elements and the method of accessing them.

For example, among other posts here, I've read the following to try and figure out the process of intepreting something seemingly similar. [How to access a dictionary key value present inside a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521892/how-to-access-a-dictionary-key-value-present-inside-a-list)

Please let me know if I structured the distanceMatrixReturn on this post poorly. I spaced it to try and make it more readable, I hope I've achieved that.

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: Are you trying to find the `2.8 mi` that can be in any given `row` or `element`? Or are you asking if there's another way to do `distanceMatrixReturn['...']['...']['....']` a whole bunch of times?

Comment: It's not simple to access data if your json is deeply nested, what I would like to suggest is you try some map reduce functions in python. http://www.python-course.eu/lambda.php

Comment: Try `distanceMatrixReturn['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration_in_traffic']['distance']['text']`

Comment: Hey Eli, sorry! Didn't post the question really but more just implied it. 
My question is how would I go about accessing that 2.8 mi value thats so deeply nested in there?

Essentially I have a whole set of these dictionaries that I queried from Google Maps API and want to parse(?) through them all and compare them. But that parts not so hard, once I figure out how to access any value I want from in that dictionary.

Thanks for the replies everyone else, I will check them out!

Answer (score 1):

Your dictionary is broken, so it's hard to imagine the right path. Anyway.

```
from operator import getitem

path = ["rows", 0, "elements", 0, "duration_in_traffic", "distance", "text"]

reduce(getitem, path, distanceMatrixReturn)  # -> "2.8 mi"
```

On Python 3 you will have to import `reduce` from `functools` first.

Comment: Is my dictionaries structure broken/wrong? 

Here it is without mucking with it at all for readability on this website.

{{'destination_addresses': ['This would be  ADDRESS 1'], 'status': 'OK', 'rows': [{'elements': [{'duration_in_traffic': {'text': '10 mins', 'value': 619}, 'status': 'OK', 'distance': {'text': '2.8 mi', 'value': 4563}, 'duration': {'text': '9 mins', 'value': 540}}]}], 'origin_addresses': ['This would be ADDRESS 2']}

That said, I will checkout your solution! Thanks.

Comment: @OhVeeOh as posted in your question, it is invalid Python syntax.

Comment: @OhVeeOh It's still invalid. You've messed it up somehow.

Comment: Ok, I will disect it closely and go to the root of the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

While ugly, it's pretty straightforward:

```
distanceMatrixReturn['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration_in_traffic']['distance']['text']
```

There's not really any *cleaner* way to do this, unless you want to create `namedtuple`s or classes, but effectively you're still going to parse out the data the same way - you'll just break it out over different parts of your program.

As for which option is best - the needs of your program will dictate that.

Comment: This is the most straightforward way to resolve the problem, but I'm thinking if there's a proper way to use map reduce functions in python.

Comment: You *could* do something convoluted like write a function that iterates through your structures until it finds some *thing* that you're looking for, but that would be error prone and tedious. And in some cases, sloooooow, especially if you're doing it a lot.

Comment: I would agree with that, if he want find random elements in the sub dictionaries, reduce function would be painful.

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to access `2.8 mi` from `distanceMatrixReturn`, you could do this:

```
 distanceMatrixReturn['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration_in_traffic']['distance']['text']
```

Comment: He's looking for some cleaner solution actually.