# Search nested dictionary values in a list and return whole nested dictionary that contains searched value

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

I have this list below

```
_list_ = [{'key1': value1, 'key2': value2}, {'key1': value3, 'key2': value4}]
```

How do I search (case insensitive) the values of key2 and return that whole dictionary containing them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521892/how-to-access-a-dictionary-key-value-present-inside-a-list

Comment: I didn't search properly, thanks for the answer very quick indeed