# How to get values from a list of dictionary?

Tags: python, python-2.7

How to get the values from a list of dictionary??
For example: I want to get the output as 2?

```
data = [{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}]
```

Below is the error am observing.

```
data['b']
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    data['b']
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: `data[0]['b']`. This ain't a dictionary but a list of dictionaries

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access a dictionary key value present inside a list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521892/how-to-access-a-dictionary-key-value-present-inside-a-list)

Answer (score -1):

The dictionary is the *first* element in `data`, so you can access it with:

```
data[0]['b']
```

If you have multiple dictionaries and you aim want to use them in a *fallback* order, you can use:

```
def obtain_value(list_of_dicts,key):
    for dict in list_of_dicts:
        if key in dict:
            return dict[key]
    raise KeyError('Could not find key \'%s\''%key)
```

and then call it with `obtain_value(data,'b')`.