# List inside a list - how to access an element

Tags: python, list, dictionary

This is my code:

```
def liveGame(summonerName):
req = requests.get('https://br1.api.riotgames.com/lol/spectator/v3/active-games/by-summoner/' + str(summonerName) + '?api_key=' + apikey)
req_args = json.loads(req.text)
print(req_args)
```

And this is what I'm receiving from my request.get:

```
{
    'gameId': 1149933395,
    'mapId': 11,
    'participants': [
        {
            'teamId': 100,
            'spell1Id': 11,
            'spell2Id': 4,
            'championId': 141,
            'profileIconId': 7,
            'summonerName': 'Disneyland Party',
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

I've simplified the return of the request, but as you can see the 'participants' index is another list. So, how can I access the contents of this list (teamId, Spell1Id, etc)?

I can only access the full list this way:

```
print(req_args['participants'])
```

But, what I want to do is access only one element of the 'participants' list.

I'm using Python 3.6.

Comment: You have a list inside a dictionary, not a list inside a list. And once you have accessed the full list, you can index into it *like any other list*.

Comment: Also, the `participants` list in your example has only one element in it. Should we assume there may be more than one element? If so, which of those elements to you want to access? The first one? All of them, one by one? Or what?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access a dictionary key value present inside a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521892/how-to-access-a-dictionary-key-value-present-inside-a-list)

Comment: @jonrsharpe Maybe I have a dictionary inside a dictionary no? But how can i access this? I'm trying this way: print(req_args['participants']['gameId']) but dosen't work.

Comment: You have a dictionary inside a list inside a dictionary, there's no maybe about it. The error you've got tells you exactly why that doesn't work.

Comment: @MichaelGeary one element? There's 'teamId', 'spell1Id', 'championId', a lot of them... I can access just one of them.

Comment: @ChandanPurbia no duplicate, can't solve the problem with the replies of this example.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Using ~ print(req_args['participants']['teamId']) ~ I have KeyError.
Using ~ print(req_args['participants'][1]) ~ I have nothing.

Comment: `teamId` and the like are not elements of the `participants` list. The `participants` list in the example has only a single element. That element is a dictionary. The names you mentioned are keys in that dictionary, not elements of the `participants` list. This is an important distinction. It sounds like your actual `participants` list may likely have more than one element, in which case each of those elements would probably have `teamId` and the other keys. But the example does not make this clear.

Comment: Then your structure is not what you've shown. You wouldn't get a KeyError from a list.

Comment: @MichaelGeary Oh, cool, now i get it. So how i access the keys of participants individually?

Comment: Vivek's answer has some good examples for you.

Comment: Yeah, the Vivek's answer solved my problem! Thanks for the help guys, and sorry for my stupidity trying to explain my problem, i'm starting now to learn new with Python. Cheers!

Comment: @JorgeNachtigall We're all glad to help, and best wishes in your adventure of learning Python. You are off to a great start. And remember: The only stupid question is the one not asked! ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access this list items using index as you do for normal list
If you want to access first element for req_args['participants'] you can use

```
req_args['participants'][i]
```

where i is nothing but the index of item that you want to access from list.

Since  items inside linked list are dictionaries to access teamId and spellId of only one item ( in this case first item) you can do following

```
req_args['participants'][0]['teamId']
req_args['participants'][0]['spell1Id']
```

you can also iterate over list to access each dictionary and value of teamId, spell1Id or others keys present inside dictionary like this

```
for participant in req_args['participants']:
    print(participant['teamId'])
    print(participant['spell1Id'])
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir! The second example is exactly what i'm looking for! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

this is simple to get value from dictionary object.

print items['participants'][0].get('teamId')

print items['participants'][0].get('spell1Id')