# Accessing a dictionary inside a list Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

say I have this list with dictionaries. How do I access multiple values? like if I want to list all these names in a string?

```
[{'name': 'Bart'},{'name': 'Lisa'},{'name': 'Maggie'},{'name': 'Homer'},{'name': 'Marge'}]
```

Comment: `l[1]['name']`  where `l` stand for the list?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access a dictionary key value present inside a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521892/how-to-access-a-dictionary-key-value-present-inside-a-list)

Answer (score 1):

```
A = [{'name': 'Bart'},{'name': 'Lisa'},{'name': 'Maggie'},{'name': 'Homer'},{'name': 'Marge'}]
A[1]['name']
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
a=[{'name': 'Bart'},{'name': 'Lisa'},{'name': 'Maggie'},{'name': 'Homer'},{'name': 'Marge'}]
```

then use index

```
    a[1]

>> {'name': 'Lisa'}

    a[1]['name']
```

Answer (score 0):

To access the element of the dictionary you can call the specific key or use the method .values()
To access the element of the list You simply have to declare the index.

Therefore, to access 'Lisa' you need to, assume that your list is named l:

```
d = l[1] # 1 is the position of the list containing the dict with 'Lisa'
# now d is the dictionary {'name':'Lisa'}
d['name'] 

# in one line:
l[1]['name']

# alternatively, but the output is a different object:
l[1].values()
```