# How do I use the value of a key-value pair of a dictionary nested inside a list in a conditional statement?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested, conditional-statements

I searched a lot of similar posts on stack overflow, but I was not able to find anything even close to my particular issue, Forgive me in advance if this was asked and answered before.

I started learning Python programming 5 days ago and right now I'm trying to make a particular program which does a blind election. I take the inputs - name and bid amount and store them as a dictionary in a list. Multiple such inputs lead to a list with a lot of dictionaries nested within it. I defined a function which loops through the different inputs in the final list of dictionaries and finds out the highest bid.

From my understanding and as confirmed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521892/how-to-access-a-dictionary-key-value-present-inside-a-list) post, I need to first index the correct element in the first square brackets and then point to the required key in the next square brackets.

I had implemented this in my code but I get this particular error nonetheless.

````
```Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "main.py", line 36, in <module>
      blind_auction_result()
    File "main.py", line 14, in blind_auction_result
      if (total_bids[bidder]["amount"]) > max_bid:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict```
````

The code that I used is as follows:

```
from replit import clear
from art import logo
total_bids = []
auction_active = True
def blind_auction_input(name,bid):
    auction_bids = {}
    auction_bids = {"name": name, "amount": bid}
    total_bids.append(auction_bids)
    print(total_bids)
def blind_auction_result():
    max_bid = 0
    bid_index = 0
    for bidder in total_bids:
        if (total_bids[bidder]["amount"]) > max_bid:
            max_bid = total_bids[bidder]["amount"]
            bid_index = bidder
    # print(f"The winner of this auction is {total_bids[bid_index]["name"]} who bid {total_bids[bid_index]["amount"]} $")
print(logo)
print("Welcome to todays' blind auction !")
while auction_active:
    bidder_name = input("What is your name?\n").lower()
    bid_amount = round(int(input("How much is your bid?\n")),2)
    while type(bid_amount) != int:
        bid_amount = round(int(input("Invalid input. Please enter a valid number.\n")),2)
    blind_auction_input(bidder_name,bid_amount)
    user_choice = input("Are there more bidders? Y or N.\n").lower()
    while not user_choice == "y" and not user_choice == "n":
        user_choice = input("Invalid input. Try again. Are there more bidders? Y or N.\n").lower()
    if user_choice == "y":
        auction_active = True
        clear()
    elif user_choice == "n":
        break
blind_auction_result()
```

Also, there is a line that I have commented out because apparently that was also showing an error, and I was able to run this only after commenting it out. I'm out of ideas on how to solve this particular case, some help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Your main issue is your loop. `for bidder in total_bids:` sets `bidder` to the actual dict not the index. So inside the loop, you can use `bidder]["amount"]` directly. Also, you don't need to do all that work. You can get the max dict directly with: `max_bidder = max(total_bids, key=lambda b: b['amount'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change that loop in `blind_auction_result` into

```py
    for bidder in total_bids:
        if bidder["amount"] > max_bid:
            max_bid = bidder["amount"]
```

`for bidder in total_bids` means that you're iterating through list items and use each item in each step. So no need to fetch them again.

Comment: Thank you m8, The program runs now when I took out the reference to total_bids.